# Python - Playwright timeout

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I'm using Playwright to upload a file and download the result.  When the inputfiles are large, and it takes a long time to process I get a timeout from playwright; it takes to long for the button "Download" to appear.

```
    raise exception
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000.0ms exceeded while waiting for event "download"
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for event "download"
============================================================
```

How can I let playwright wait longer on that specific event?

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.locator("text=Download").click()
    #todo: wait longer?
download = download_info.value
# expect(page).to_have_url("http://localhost:8080/swagger/#/NER/post_ner")
path = download.path()
suggested_filename = file_out
download.save_as(suggested_filename)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you know that the `click` will take a while, you can set a timeout:

```
page.locator("text=Download").click(timeout=60000)
```

Comment: Adding on, remember that the timeout is in ms.

Comment: I tried this: age.locator("text=Download").click(timeout=120000), but it's ignored.  I get the same error message: playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000.0ms exceeded while waiting for event "download"
This worked: page.set_default_timeout(timeout=120000)

Comment: I don't think the timeout here applies to the action triggered by the click, only the wait until the click can be fired on a visible element.

Comment: @ggorlen I had to double-check that it the source code and the timeout also applies to the navigation as well.

Comment: I also checked that it's mentioned in the docs @ggorlen :) "When all steps combined have not finished during the specified timeout, this method throws a TimeoutError. Passing zero timeout disables this." "all steps combined"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but I have used the code below successfully many times:

```
with page.expect_download(timeout=0) as download_info:
```

Setting timeout=0 causes it to wait for as long as it takes to download.

Comment: Timeout of 0 is excessive. If an action doesn't work in a few hours or days at the very most, it's best to fail with a clear error message rather than block forever.

Comment: @ggorlen Based on how fast file will be downloaded... Like if site gives you small speed, timeout=0 can be used.

Comment: I don't think there are any files that take forever to download. Surely, after a few hours or days, you should give up and avoid an effective infinite loop so you can debug the script with a clear error or retry the action. I'm just repeating my above comment, though. Something like, say, `timeout=86400000` (24 hours) is far prefereable to 0 in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the timeout to 0 if your not concerned with it taking too long. Though this can lead to it potentially taking hours...or never end if it gets stuck loading. A timeout of some value other than 0 is probably best practice.

page.locator("text=Download").click(timeout=0)

Comment: I tried that, was also ignored.
Thanks for your reply.